# How can I get this effect (lines in an input)?

Tags: css, website-design

How can I get this effect (lines in an input)?

[image: line-effect]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a background CSS image for a text area.

```
textarea {background:url(http://www.example.com/your_image.jpg;}
```

Comment: .........bingo!

Comment: Beware to control the line-height and font-size explicitly to match your background image or your end result could be terrible.

Comment: I am imagining horrible yellow legal pad... :P